# Combined two lambda functions into one?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, pymongo

I have two MongoDB collection 1) profile 2) post. I have created two Lambda functions. Find the below code along with the Lambda functions name.

1) testuserid

```py
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=1))

    Username = event['username']

    disuid = list(db.profile.find({"username" : Username},{"_id" : 1}))
    uid = json.dumps(disuid, default=json_util.default)
    return json.loads(uid)
```

I have passed the username in event and i get the output  _id.

2) testpostid

```py
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=1))

    Userid = event['userid']
    uid = ObjectId(Userid)

    disposts = list(db.post.find({"userid" : uid}))
    posts = json.dumps(disposts, default=json_util.default)
    return json.loads(posts)
```

I have passed the value of 1st Lambda function output as userid and get the post collection all the matched details.

Now my concern is, how to combined this two lambda functions and get the output combined.  I mean 1st Lambda function _id and 2nd Lambda function post collection data in array. Is it possible to combined two lambda functions?

Comment: Input to both the function is different. How will you combine the two input?

Comment: You'll need to be more specific about what you mean by "combine". Do you mean taking the two functions and merging them into one? Chaining the function calls so that the output of one is immediately used as input for the other? Creating a separate function that invokes both of these functions in sequence? There are far too many meanings for the word "combine" to determine what kind of solution you're looking for. Please elaborate so we can help you more effectively.

Comment: @AbhishekGarg thanks for your response, both inputs are different but 1st lambda output, we will use second lambda function input. I think, combined word suitable or not i don't know but i need the output of both lambda functions in array. is there any provision.

Comment: @B.Fleming Thanks for your response. I think combine word is suitable or not, i don't know. My concern is both outputs will display in one array in one lambda function. And one more thing 1st lambda function output, we will use as a input of 2nd lambda function input.

Comment: @B.Fleming Can you please help me out with the solutions.

Comment: Try with aggregation and $lookup stage. Say if you don't find the right query, i'll have time to redact a more precise answer later.

Comment: @matthPen Thanks for your response. I didn't find any right query. Instead aggregation and $lookup, any other solution. Can you please help me out the other solution.

Comment: @matthPen Can youplease help me out with the solution, please find the below link of query   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57496378/how-to-do-multiple-joins-between-two-collection-in-mongodb-using-lambda-function/57505217?noredirect=1#comment101497444_57505217

Comment: @B.Fleming Can you please help me out the solution, please find the below link of query    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57496378/how-to-do-multiple-joins-between-two-collection-in-mongodb-using-lambda-function/57505217?noredirect=1#comment101497444_57505217